# Iterating over subprocess output results in non-zero exit code when breaking out of the loop

Tags: python, subprocess

The following snippet results in the subprocess finishing with zero exit code:

```
with subprocess.Popen("print.sh", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) as process:
    for line in iter(process.stdout):
        break
        print(line)
    process.wait()
    print(f'Subprocess exit code: {process.returncode}')

# Subprocess exit code: 0
```

whereas when [`TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) is used the exit code is non-zero:

```
with subprocess.Popen("print.sh", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) as process:
    for line in io.TextIOWrapper(process.stdout, encoding="utf-8"):
        break
        print(line)
    process.wait()
    print(f'Subprocess exit code: {process.returncode}')

# Subprocess exit code: -13
```

What is the reason for the non-zero exit code in the second snippet?

Python 3.7.9

Comment: Signal 13 happens when the process tries to write to a pipe with no reader.

Comment: Exiting from the `TextIOWrapper` context is closing the pipe.

Comment: @Woodford You probably need a less trivial `print.sh`, that writes more data to the pipe.

Comment: Yes, I don't get non-zero code for a handful of `echo` commands either. I increased their number to 40 and that resulted in -13 again. Sorry, wasn't aware of this when I was writing the question.

Answer (score 1):

As @Barmar noted in the comments, `TextIOWrapper` is closing the underlying handle (`process.stdout`) when the for loop exits. This is intended behavior ([if frequently undesired](https://bugs.python.org/issue21363)).

The `-13` return code comes from the subprocess trying to write to a broken pipe and raising a `SIGPIPE` signal. From the [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.returncode) docs:

> A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (POSIX only).

You can work around this in your example by extending the lifetime of the `TextIOWrapper`:

```py
with subprocess.Popen(["cat", "/usr/share/dict/words"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) as process:
    utf8 = io.TextIOWrapper(process.stdout, encoding='utf-8')
    for line in utf8:
        break
        print(line)
    process.wait()
    print(f'Subprocess exit code: {process.returncode}')
```

Comment: A simpler fix (on Python 3.6+) is to just pass `encoding='utf-8'` to the `Popen` constructor so it wraps the process's `stdout` for you; no need to explicitly use `io.TextIOWrapper` at all (or more precisely, no need for *you* to use it; `subprocess` does the work for you). That'll mean only one handle, that doesn't get closed independently by accident.